# AutoLayout constraint animation scales from wrong point

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to achieve an animation using autolayout constraints, working together with UIStackViews. There is one animation I am getting stuck with.

I have an UIImageView (green) nested in an UIView (orange), that's in turn handled by a UIStackView. When only those elements are left visible, the views should shrink. I am trying to change the following constraints:

[image: The constraints of the Views]

Normally at 64 for width and height and 10 for the leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints, I am using the following method to change them to 46 and 7 respectively:

```
private func setImageShrunk() {
    imageWidth.constant = 46
    imageHeight.constant = 46
    imageTopMargin.constant = 7
    imageBottomMargin.constant = 7
    imageRightMargin.constant = 7
    imageLeftMargin.constant = 7
}
```

This function is called by another function:

```
func shrinkImage(animated: Bool) {
    if(animated) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.setImageShrunk()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    } else {
        setImageShrunk()
    }
}
```

Shrinking the image without animation returns the expected result, of course abruptly. However, trying to animate it, I am getting the following result:

[image: Animation mishap]

**I want the view to shrink towards the top left corner**, instead it shrinks from the center. It shouldn't "move first, scale later". Does anyone know how to achieve this using AutoLayout in iOS 11?

Comment: What happens if you use 0 instead of 7 for top and left margins?

Comment: Sorry I thought margins are for orange view and its super view. you can set constraints for top and left of orange view to its super view and set them 0 in shrinkImage method

Comment: @AliMoazenzadeh the constraints to the top and left were already set to 0, which is why it's so baffling to me that this happens

Comment: can you try set top and left margins constraints priority to something lower than 1000? 990 for example

Comment: @AliMoazenzadeh I already tried playing with the priorities, and the result ends up [even weirder](https://imgur.com/uwzIxs4)...

Comment: You mention *"handled by a UIStackView."* ... Is the first part of the animation you've shown the result of a view being hidden or removed from the Stack View? And that leaves "orange" as the only remaining arranged view? If you **don't** call `shrinkImage()`, does "orange" jump to `0,0`?

Comment: @DonMag that is correct, the first part you can see from the right is done by hiding a view in the StackView, the `onComplete()` of that animation calls `shrinkImage()`. Not calling `shrinkImage()` does not make the image jump.

Comment: @TomQDRS - ok... we probably need a bit more information, such as how your stack view is configured and constrained, and the actual code for your multi-part animation. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what happened trying to make a small project to recreate the error.

In the second project, the setup was the same but the animation worked like I expected. After some thinking I realized that in this new project, I had called the animations from the `UIViewController` **containing** the `UIStackView`.

In the original question, I had neglected to mention that **I was calling the animations from a class extending `UIStackView`, so the View to be animated itself**. Even though it had references to the constraints from the outside, the View didn't know its environment and embedding Views. That's why it just jumped and then scaled.

I fixed the problem by transferring the animations to be done to the `UIViewController` containing the `UIStackView`.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I just had to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on parent view, rather than animated view itself

Answer (score 0):

If you set width and height , then no need for the right and bottom constraints , as when you change the height from 64 to 46 , then bottom distance should be 28 ( 10 + 18 ) and since you set it to 7 , then there is a conflict , same for right , so either remove them , or lower their priorities

BTW all of this is valid only if the orange view has other constraints for width & height

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the anchor point of the UIView? It is now shrinking on the center point, instead of the top left corner. Also you should create a custom animation defining the two animation and link them together. You can find lot of solutions for this on the net, but here is an example. It is for sprite kit, but the idea is the same.

```
        #if os(iOS)
    let transform:SKAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -40, y: -45), duration: 0.3)
    let rotateAction:SKAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: degree(-20), duration: 0.3)
        #else
        let transform:SKAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -40, y: 60), duration: 0.3)
        let rotateAction:SKAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: degree(-20), duration: 0.3)
        #endif
    let endAction:SKAction = SKAction.perform(#selector(GameScene.animateToTableEnded), onTarget: self)
    let combineAction:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.group([transform, rotateAction]), endAction])
```

Actually here the grouping makes the magic.

Here is a solution for core animations from the Apple documentation.

```
let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
fadeOut.fromValue = 1
fadeOut.toValue = 0
fadeOut.duration = 1

let expandScale = CABasicAnimation()
expandScale.keyPath = "transform"
expandScale.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionScale)
expandScale.fromValue = [1, 1, 1]
expandScale.toValue = [3, 3, 3]

let fadeAndScale = CAAnimationGroup()
fadeAndScale.animations = [fadeOut, expandScale]
fadeAndScale.duration = 1
```